# Check for defined characters in string input

Tags: c

I've been reading some stuff about C, i'm a beginner and at this point this is where i'm at:

This function keeps the input from the keyboard:

```
void store_sequence(char *arg) {
    strcpy(estado.seq, arg);
    estado.tamanho = strlen(arg);
}
```

and this is what i came so far to check if there are As on the string that was inserted on the keyboard:

```
void sequence_does_contain_As_and_Bs(char *arg) {

  char buf [] = estado.seq;

  s = strchr (buf, 'A');

  if (s != NULL)
    printf ("found a 'A' at %s\n", s);

}
```

So, basically, i need to detect if the input string has only As and Bs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/

Particularly `strspn()` and `strcspn()`

Comment: THans SpacedMonkey, i came to this:

´int sequencia_nao_contem_so_As_e_Bs(char *arg){
    int i;
    char cset[] = "CDEFGHIJLMNOPQRSTUVXYZcdefghijlmnopqrstuvxyz";
    
    i = strspn (arg,cset);
    return ("%d",i);
}´

and this doesn't allow me to put HGBGD and it's fine, because i want only "ABABABBABBBA" characters with A and B, but if i put HFDHDAB it accepts

Comment: `if ( strspn(arg, "AB") == strlen(arg) ) /* only As and Bs */`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
char buf [] = estado.seq;
int len = estado.tamanho;
int i;
int contains = 1;
for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    if (buf[i] != 'A' && buf[i] != 'B') {
        contains = 0;
        break;
    }
if (contains)
  // do whatever you want if the string contains only As and Bs
```